# 301 redirect https (old site) to http (new site) in htaccess or otherwise

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I must have read every answer here 100 times but I still cannot get this to work (maybe my VPS) but I am also pesting my hosts and they cant crack it either.

Old website https://www.olddomain.co.uk i want to 301 to new website http://newdomain.com.

I have tried every conceivable htaccess code / rules I can find but still no good.

Any ideas these are the 2 I have been working with below but seems like htaccess doesn't recognise the SSL and therefore run the rule to redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on

# First rule - if this is an SSL connection, then redirect
# to http://enginecoreplugs.com then stop processing other rules
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://enginecoreplugs.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Second rule - all other requests, redirect to http://enginecoreplugs.com.
RewriteRule (.*) http://enginecoreplugs.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If it helps at all, old website I am wanting to 301 = https://www.enginecoreplugs.co.uk new website = http://enginecoreplugs.com.

Thanks in advance!!

Will

Answer (score 0):

I had everything correct.

This ended up being some stupid problem at the hosts forwarding the https versions.